# Can I use single quotations in an object name?

Tags: java, oop

I need to name an Object: **Dave's Account**

I'm trying to do this using the following code:

```
Account Dave's Account = new Account;
```

but it's not working, I need the single quotation to be part of the name, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the name of a **variable**, not the name of an object. Objects don't have a name.

And no, you may not have quotes, nor spaces, in a variable name. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

```
Identifier:
    IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral

IdentifierChars:
    JavaLetter
    IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit

JavaLetter:
    any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)

JavaLetterOrDigit:
    any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
```